# How can I change 'history' command output?

Tags: terminal, command-line, history

So by default .bash_history stores *500* last used commands. I changed that to *5000* by setting `HISTFILESIZE=5000` in `.bash_profile` It seems to work.

Now when I do `history` it still prints **500** commands, but now it does so **not** from **1 to 500**, but from **36 to 535** (earlier commands are stored but not printed).

I'd like for `history` to print *1000* last used commands. How can I achieve that?

Also recently I tried `history -a` and haven't noticed anything change. What does this command do? Man history doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `HISTFILESIZE`, you also need to set `HISTSIZE`, which controls the number of commands to keep in memory until they are saved.

Also, the manual page for `history` is available via `man bash`.  Scroll down to `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`, and you'll find it.  The details about `HISTSIZE` and other variables are further up in the same manual page.